# Difference between hidden, scattered and specified coupling?

Tags: c++, coupling

What is the difference between these types of component coupling and when should one prefer a specific type over the others?

Comment: These are not standard terms in C++. You need to ask whoever used them.

Comment: It's not 100% clear how those concepts map to C++.